# Maximize Target Sum By Filtering Input Features

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

| Feature 1 | Feature 2 | ... | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.7 | 0.3 | ... | 1.4 |
| 0.4 | 0.45 | ... | -2 |
| 0.7 | 0.15 | ... | -2.5 |
| 0.8 | 0.9 | ... | -3 |
| 1 | 0.4 | ... | 1.5 |
| -1.5 | 0.1 | ... | 0.25 |

Imagine I have a dataset with almost 100 features containing 80.000 rows, and my overall goal is to maximize the target sum while having a minimum target goal (like 200 in total sum). The process is simply considering target predictions that are positive while ignoring the negative ones.

I have already tried regression techniques, but it seems to over-generalize and it focuses on minimizing overall loss instead of focusing only on maximizing the sum returns.

On the other hand, I have manually tried to filter some features and I've had an initial success but it's not optimal.

As an example from the table above, I would like a technique that tells me the optimal range of each feature is : feature 1 > 0.5 and feature 2 between 0.2 and 0.5 => only 1st row and 5th row will match, and my total would be 1.4 + 1.5 = 2.9 total sum as an example). Afterwards, I'll try out these range parameters for the test set and see if they yield a good return or not.

So my question is which techniques allow me to make this process of filtering out multiple features optimally and maximizing the target sum without overfitting of course ?

Or is there any way to do it through machine learning, but get the model to focus on maximizing the total returns?

Comment: I expect there are not so many replies here since it's not so clear what is "target sum"? Or maybe this is just my problem. Anyway, what do you want in the end? Could you please provide me with an example 2 predictors (3 observations) and 1 target?

Comment: What I want is find the optimal range for each feature out of the 100 (or just ignore some features if it won't help) so that when I sum all the targets I get at least 200 (my target goal). For example: Without filtering the sum of my targets is a negative value, and I want a technique that tells me if feature 1 > 0.5 and feature 2 between 0.2 and 0.5 and so on I'll have a smaller dataset containing only hundreds of rows but with the sum of targets close to my target goal.

Comment: As far as I understand this an optimization problem, not a prediction problem: you want to find the features values which make the sum across targets maximal, right? If yes, I think [genetic learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) is a good candidate.

Comment: Tip: you should use `@user` when you reply to a comment, otherwise the other person doesn't know that you replied (you receive notifications automatically for your own post).